# Convert PDF to Word

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf

I have a PDF document that I want to convert to Microsoft Word. How can I accomplish this without having to buy something or set up an account on someone's web site?  I'm looking for an actionable solution (how to do it), not a list of software or web services that might be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Did you tried to open PDF file with MS Word? Actually it should open it(at least 2013 can do that for sure). Another option is to use [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) and open PDF there then `save as` word document(docx). Keep in mind that not all PDF files contain editable characters but a picture(snapshot) which would be visible to Word as an image. You can try in such cases OCR software to do recognition of characters in images if you need editable version of PDF.

Comment: Yes, beginning with 2013 (and continuing with 2016) Word can open PDFs and can make them editable if they are of the correct type (essentially: not scanned).